# How can a gem be shown in "bundle show" but not be in the Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Running

```
bundle show
```

Lists rake (10.0.4) and i18n (0.6.1) amongst other gems, however they are not listed in the Gemfile. **Why / how** are [gems which aren't in the Gemfile] listed?

The problem I'm having is that one machine (mac osx) following bundle install, has all these gems which are necessary for the rails application to run, whereas another machine (ubuntu 13.04) does not get these non-Gemfile gems.

I am using rbenv and bundler to manage dependencies. I believe this is a problem with my understanding of gemfiles

Comment: The specific problem I was having with the ubuntu machine, is that I had forgotten I had not got binstubs to work on it. When I remembered, I tried again, failed, so conceded preceding my commands with "bundle exec". Derp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each gem you add to the `Gemfile` can have dependencies. You can check out the `Gemfile.lock` to see them. Bundler will install these dependencies even though they are not specifically listed in the `Gemfile`. For more info, you can view the [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) site.